# Creating a reference to a hash table element

Tags: powershell, reference, hashtable

So, I'm trying to create a tree-type variable that I could use for data navigation. I've ran into an issue while trying to use reference variables on hash tables in PowerShell. Consider the following code:

```
$Tree = @{ TextValue = "main"; Children = @() }
$Item = @{ TextValue = "sub"; Children = @() }
$Pointer = [ref] $Tree.Children
$Pointer.Value += $Item
$Tree
```

When checking reference variable `$Pointer`, it shows appropriate values, but main variable `$Tree` is not affected. Is there no way to create references to a hash table element in PowerShell, and I'll have to switch to a 2-dimensional array?

Edit with more info:

I've accepted Mathias' answer, as using `List` looks like exactly what I need, but there's a little more clarity needed on how arrays and references interact. Try this code:

```
$Tree1 = @()
$Pointer = $Tree1
$Pointer += 1
Write-Host "tree1 is " $Tree1
$Tree2 = @()
$Pointer = [ref] $Tree2
$Pointer.Value += 1
Write-Host "tree2 is " $Tree2
```

As you can see from the output, it is possible to get a reference to an array and then modify the size of the array via that reference. I thought it would also work if an array is an element of another array or a hash table, but it does not. PowerShell seems to handle those differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect this to be an unfortunate side-effect of the way `+=` works on arrays.

When you use `+=` on a fixed-size array, PowerShell replaces the original array with a new (and bigger) array. We can verify that `$Pointer.Value` no longer references the same array with `GetHashCode()`:

```
PS C:\> $Tree = @{ Children = @() }
PS C:\> $Pointer = [ref]$Tree.Children
PS C:\> $Tree.Children.GetHashCode() -eq $Pointer.Value.GetHashCode()
True
PS C:\> $Pointer.Value += "Anything"
PS C:\> $Tree.Children.GetHashCode() -eq $Pointer.Value.GetHashCode()
False
```

---

One way of going about this is to avoid using `@()` and `+=`.

You could use a `List` type instead:

```
$Tree = @{ TextValue = "main"; Children = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject] }
$Item = @{ TextValue = "sub"; Children = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject] }
$Pointer = [ref] $Tree.Children
$Pointer.Value.Add($Item)
$Tree
```

Comment: Indeed (+1); a more direct way of testing whether two variables / expressions refer to the same instance of a reference type: `[object]::ReferenceEquals($Tree.Children, $Pointer.Value)`; I recommend using `[object]` rather than `[psobject]` - it's better to treat the latter as an invisible helper type (and only use it via its `[pscustomobject]` alias when you need to construct custom objects ad hoc).

Comment: Abstraction is so helpful at times.  Don't arrays have an `Add` method on them, though?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I'll give `List` a try and see how it goes.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Yes, arrays have an `.Add()` method due to implementing the [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist) interface, but it is useless and always fails with `Collection was of a fixed size.`

Answer (score 3):

To [complement Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen):

- Indeed, **any *array* is of *fixed size* and cannot be extended *in place*** (`@()` creates an empty `[object[]]` array).
- **`+=` in PowerShell quietly creates a *new* array**, with a copy of all the original elements plus the new one(s), and assigns *that* to the LHS.

---

**Your use of `[ref]` is pointless**, because `$Pointer = $Tree.Children` alone is sufficient to copy the *reference* to the array stored in `$Tree.Children`.

<sup>See bottom section for a discussion of appropriate uses of `[ref]`.</sup>

Thus,  *both* `$Tree.Children` and `$Pointer` would then contain a reference to the same array, just as `$Pointer.Value` does in your `[ref]`-based approach.

Because `+=` creates a *new* array, however, whatever is on the LHS - be it `$Pointer.Value` or, without `[ref]`, just `$Pointer` - simply receives a *new* reference to the *new* array, whereas `$Tree.Children` still points to the old one.

You can verify this by using **the direct way to determine whether two variables or expressions "point" to the same instance of a *reference type*** (which all collections are):

```
PS> [object]::ReferenceEquals($Pointer.Value, $Tree.Children)
False
```

Note that `[object]::ReferenceEquals()` is only applicable to [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types), not [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) - variables containing the latter store values *directly* instead of *referencing* data stored *elsewhere*.

---

Mathias' approach solves your problem by using a [`` [List`1] ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) instance instead of an array, which can be *extended in place* with its `.Add()` method, so that the reference stored in `$Pointer[.Value]` never needs to change and continues to refer to the same list as `$Tree.Children`.

---

**Regarding your follow-up question: appropriate uses of `[ref]`**:

```
$Tree2 = @()
$Pointer = [ref] $Tree2
```

In this case, **because `[ref]` is applied to a *variable* - as designed - it creates an effective *variable alias***: `$Pointer.Value` *keeps* pointing to whatever `$Tree2` contains even if different data is assigned to `$Tree2` later (irrespective of whether that data is a value-type or reference-type instance):

```
PS> $Tree2 = 'Now I am a string.'; $Pointer.Value
Now I am a string.
```

Also note that **the typical `[ref]` use case is to pass variables to functions to *.NET API methods* that have `ref` or `out` parameters**; while you *can* use it with PowerShell scripts and functions too in order to pass *by-reference* parameters, as shown in the following example, this is best avoided:

```
# Works, but best avoided in PowerShell code.
PS> function foo { param([ref] $vRef) ++$vRef.Value }; $v=1; foo ([ref] $v); $v
2  # value of $v was incremented via $vRef.Value
```

---

By contrast, **you cannot use `[ref]` to create such a persistent *indirect* reference to *data***, such as the *property* of an object *contained* in a variable, and use of `[ref]` is essentially pointless there:

```
$Tree2 = @{ prop = 'initial val' }
$Pointer = [ref] $Tree2.prop   # [ref] is pointless here
```

Later changing `$Tree2.prop` is *not* reflected in `$Pointer.Value`, because `$Pointer.Value` *statically* refers to the reference *originally* stored in `$Tree2.prop`:

```
PS> $Tree2.prop = 'later val'; $Pointer.Value
initial val   # $Pointer.Value still points to the *original* data
```

PowerShell should arguably *prevent* use of `[ref]` with anything that is *not a variable*. However, there is a legitimate - albeit exotic - "off-label" use for `[ref]`, for facilitating updating values in the caller's scope *from descendant scopes*, as shown in the conceptual [about_Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Ref#references-and-scopes) help topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the pointer into your tree structure:

```
$Tree = @{ TextValue = "main"; Children = [ref]@() }
$Item1 = @{ TextValue = "sub1"; Children = [ref]@() }
$Item2 = @{ TextValue = "sub2"; Children = [ref]@() }
$Item3 = @{ TextValue = "subsub"; Children = [ref]@() }
$Pointer = $Tree.Children
$Pointer.Value += $Item1
$Pointer.Value += $Item2
$Pointer.Value.Get(0).Children.Value += $Item3

function Show-Tree {
  param ( [hashtable] $Tree )

  Write-Host $Tree.TextValue
  if ($Tree.Children.Value.Count -ne 0) {
    $Tree.Children.Value | ForEach-Object { Show-Tree $_ }
  }
}

Show-Tree $Tree
```

Output:

```
main
sub1
subsub
sub2
```